# Import multiples DAG to Google Composer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I need to change the way we import DAGs into Airflow/Composer as we need to do it by blocks (groups of DAGs).

Currently we use the command:

```
gcloud composer environments storage dags import --environment=ENVIRONMENT --location=LOCATION --source=SOURCE
```

That allows to put a folder as source, the problem is that this folder is also copied to the Airflow bucket.
Example:

```
foo
|
+-- file1.txt
+-- file2.txt
+-- file3.txt
```

```
gcloud composer environments storage dags import --environment=ENVIRONMENT --location=LOCATION --source=/foo
```

```
gs://composer-bucket
|
+-- dags
|   |
|   +-- foo
|   |   |
|   |   |
|   |   +-- file1.txt
|   |   +-- file2.txt
|   |   +-- file3.txt
```

I know that it is possible to manually copy the dags to the Composer bucket using this command.

```
gsutil -m cp foo/*.py gs://composer-bucket
```

That way I can send several files without the problem of the other command.

Is there something additional that does `gcloud composer` and not `gsutil cp`?
Is there any way to use `gcloud composer` without having the problem of the source folder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My best guess is that using gsutil will be just fine as an alternative to gcloud dags import.  I looked at the REST API described here https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.environments#Environment and could find no import equivalent.  This makes me feel that the gcloud import is "basically" doing a get of the environment to find the identity of the target GCS bucket and then performing the equivalent of a gsutil cp to that target.

Answer (score 0):

Previously wildcards was supported in `gcloud composer` and `source` but apparently it's not case now.

I think it's better to keep `gcloud composer` command instead of `gsutil cp` in this case because with `gcloud composer`, you don't set the `Composer` bucket name.

**Solution 1 (my preferred) :**

You can list your files in the `DAG_FOLDER` via a `Shell` script and use `gcloud composer` in a `foreach` :

```bash
export DAG_FOLDER=foo

for file in "$DAG_FOLDER"/*.py; do \
    gcloud composer environments storage dags import \
    --environment $COMPOSER_ENVIRONMENT \
    --location $ENVIRONMENT_LOCATION \
    --project $GCP_PROJECT_ID \
    --source "$file"; \
done
```

**Solution 2 :**

If you really want using `gsutil` for any reason, you can retrieve the `Composer` bucket name and then use a `gsutil cp` command as follow :

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -o pipefail
set -u

export DAG_FOLDER=foo

COMPOSER_BUCKET=$(gcloud composer environments describe "${COMPOSER_ENVIRONMENT}" \
                  --project "${GCP_PROJECT_ID}" \
                  --location "${ENVIRONMENT_LOCATION}" \
                  --format "value(config.dagGcsPrefix)" | sed -e "s/\\/dags//g")

echo "Cloud Composer bucket $COMPOSER_BUCKET"

gsutil -m cp $DAG_FOLDER/*.py "gs://$COMPOSER_BUCKET"
```

Comment: Thanks for your snippets. Honestly I don't want to use "gsutil cp" because I think "gcloud composer" does another stuff related to Airflow. In our current pipeline (this action is executed by Jenkins) we have something very similar to your solution 1, but sometimes the amount of DAG is huge and for that we need something more performant and I think if we run this command concurrently we will have memory issues.